# comprobar si un usuario existe en firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic, ionic3, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en `ionic` y tengo hecho el login con `googleAuthentication`, cuando me logueo/registro añado algunos datos a mi `firestore`, como la imagen y el email. En mi aplicación móvil permito cambiar la imagen, que lo hace respecto a los datos de la base de datos de firestore. El problema está en que el logueo al `firestore` lo tengo hecho con un set, así que cada vez que hago login, sobreescribo los datos.

Quisiera saber si hay alguna posibilidad de comprobar si el documento ya existe (el documento es igual al id del usuario, así que simplemente pasando el id del usuario ya estaría) o comprobar si el usuario ya está autenticado. Lo he intentado de diferentes formas pero soy bastante nuevo con esto y no se muy bien como tratar los datos para saber cuando está vacío y cuando no.

Dejo parte de mi código por si puede ayudar:

```js
 addUserToBbdd(user){
    let coleccion = this.db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);
 
    this.db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({"email": user.email, "image": user.photoURL, "name": user.displayName}).then(newItem => {
      //el usuario no está en la base de datos y lo inserta.
    }).catch(err =>{
      //el usuario ya está en la base de datos.
    });
  }
```

Estoy utilizando la ultima versión de Cordova, `ionic 3` y `angular 5`. la librería para el `firestore` es `angularfire2/firestore.`

Gracias de antelación.

Answer (score 2):

En base al código que has puesto para comprobar si el usuario ya existe tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
var usuario = this.db.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
usuario.get().then( usuarioBBDD => {
                       if (!usuarioBBDD .exists) {
                             console.log("No existe el usuario");
                             //Entiendo que aqui va el código para asignar el mail e imagen
                       }
                       else{
                             console.log("Existe el usuario");
                       }
                    }
```

Espero que te sirva.
Saludos.

Comment: estoy intentando usar el código pero me tira error porque no puede reconocer user en user.uid. Será que hay que declararlo? Gracias

Answer (score -1):

I use this solution:

My Service

```
     import { of } from "rxjs";
    ----------------
async addCliente(nuevocliente: Cliente) {
    var saved: boolean;
    var clienteDocument = this.clienteCollection.doc(nuevocliente.cli_cedula);
    var clienteObservable = clienteDocument.valueChanges(); //Observable<Object> de Firebase
    var cliente = of(clienteObservable); //Get Object of Observable
    await cliente.toPromise().then((cliente) => {
      if (cliente == null) {
        //Client No exists , save
        clienteDocument.set(cliente);
        saved = true;
      } else {
        //Client Exists
        console.log("Ya existe un cliente con esa cedula");
        saved = false;
      }
    });
    return saved;
  }
```

My cliente.ts

```
this.clienteService.addCliente(this.nuevocliente).then((aux) => {
      if (aux) {
        console.log("saved Successfully")
        //your awesome code here
      } else {
        console.log("Client already exist");
        //your awesome code here
      }      
    });
```

Comment: Traduce tu respesta